# How to display my categories in a list (to a post, not the sidebar)?

Tags: posts, css, list, categories

i want to display my categories to a post like a list. i have this (parent- and child-) categories:

```
- Sports
    - Football
    - Basketball
- Toys
    - Dolls
    - Lego
- Books
```

for example one post is archived to the categories "Sports", "Football", and "Books" i want to output the categories like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Sports</a>
        <ul class="children">
             <li><a href="#">Football</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Books</a></li>
</ul>
```

…as you can see, the hierarchical order by parent->child is important!

thanks,
Jochen

Answer (score 0):

Using wp_list_categories

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories

Something like this should give you what you want

```
$args = array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'title_li' => ''
    );

wp_list_categories($args);
```

Comment: unfortunately not… it gives me ALL the categories from the system (like using it in the sidebar). but i want to have just the categories displayed which are assigned to the shown post!!! like using "the_category" in single.php! i hope you know what i mean...